# Bash script to convert multiple avi in to mp4

Tags: bash

I have a lot of avi files in one folder and trying to convert them in to mp4. I am using this bash script not sure whats wrong. any idea?

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.avi;
  do name=`echo $i | cut -d'.' -f1`;
  echo $name;
  avconv -i -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental  -threads 3 "$i" "$name.mp4";
done
```

the error I get is :

```
-vcodec: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You need to put the `-i` flag directly before the input file, `"$i"` in this case.

Comment: `avconv -i "$i"-vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental  -threads 3 "$name.mp4"` should work, just to clarify @AlexR.'s answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the input file right after the `-i` switch, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.avi;
do
    name=`echo $i | cut -d'.' -f1`;
    avconv -i "$i" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental  -threads 3 "$name.mp4";
done
```

Your version was looking for an input file named "-vcodec".