# converting avi to streamable mp4

Tags: avconv, mp4, avi, lsb-release, chromecast

I just got my chromecast and I am trying to convert my uncastable avi videos to castable mp4 video format
I converted some avi videos to mp4 using the command:

```
avconv -i input_file.avi -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output_file.mp4
```

The problem is that I get the error "media not streamable" and won't work with chromecast.

Output of lsb_release -a

```
frepie@OptiPlex-760:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
frepie@OptiPlex-760:~$
```

Output of avconv -codecs | grep libvpx

```
frepie@OptiPlex-760:~$ avconv -codecs | grep libvpx
avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
DEV.L. vp8                  On2 VP8 (decoders: vp8 libvpx ) (encoders: libvpx )
frepie@OptiPlex-760:~$
```

Comment: Please  answer assuming that I know close to nothing in video/audio formats.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the oututz of `lsb_release -a`

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `avconv -codecs | grep libvpx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer I was looking for here:

[Bash script to convert multiple avi in to mp4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505503/bash-script-to-convert-multiple-avi-in-to-mp4)

The important line in the proposed script is

```
avconv -i "$i" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental  -threads 3 "$name.mp4"
```

changing "$i" for the input filename and "$name.mp4" for the desired output name.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chromecast supports two container formats, *WebM* and *MP4*.
Therefore use *WebM* and the *Google VP9* codec via the command below. Why *WebM*? *Google VP9* doesn't works with *MP4*.

```
avconv -i input_file.avi -c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a copy output_file.webm
```

or the *VP8* encoder

```
avconv -i input_file.avi -c:v libvpx -c:a copy output_file.webm
```

Comment: I don't have libvpx-vp9 on my pc. I downloaded it from http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/libvpx.html but the installation instructions given in the README file a way beyond my capacities. Is there an easy way to install libvpx-vp9 ?

Comment: Try VP8 first, I have improved my answer.